# Как делать активными пункты меню при прокрутке страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Сайт одностраничный, при нажатии ссылки переходит на определенную позицию на странице. И никак не получается сделать ссылку меню активной при переходе. Подскажите в чем проблема! Код срабатывает только для `id="#price"`

```
<div class="ui large secondary inverted pointing menu">
        <a class="toc item">
          <i class="sidebar icon"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="active item" href="#home">Home</a>
        <a class="item" href="#services">Services</a>
        <a class="item" href="#price">Price</a>`



<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $("#home, #services", #price).each(function(){
      var pos = $(this).position().top;
      var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (pos < winTop + 100) {
          $("a").addClass("active");
        }
        else{
          $("a").removeClass("active");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: 1. `$("#home, #services", #price)` -> `$("#home, #services, #price")`. 2. `$("a")` - выбирает все анкор таги на странице. 3. посмотрите описание/параметры функции `$.each` - https://api.jquery.com/each/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд, задумка в целом правильная, но реализация нерациональна. Кроме очевидной ошибки синтаксиса `$("#home, #services", #price)` и обращения ко всем ссылкам на странице `$("a")` есть некоторые претензии. `$(window).scroll` вызывается мильён раз за время прокрутки и при каждом вызове вы перебираете свои дивки, получаете их `position().top`, ищете на странице все 'a' (ну или все 'а' с определенным href, не важно), при том, что меняется только прокрутка страницы, а эти переменные постоянны.

Почему бы не собрать все это один раз, а в колбеке скролла только проверять, причем проверять с конца.

В процессе понял, что проще написать все с начала) Вот что получилось:

Пример на jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ipshenicyn/owhLpuv9/

Дальше ключевой код из примера, очищенный от лишнего

**HTML**

Ссылкам добавил класс `.scroll-to`, чтобы удобнее было с ними работать. "Якорным" блокам добавил класс `.anchor`, чтобы сделать гибко и не лазить в js-код каждый раз, когда на странице появляется новый блок.

```
<a href="#div1" class="scroll-to">div1</a>
<a href="#div2" class="scroll-to">div2</a>
<a href="#div3" class="scroll-to">div3</a>
<a href="#div4" class="scroll-to">div4</a>

<div id="div1" class="anchor"></div>
<div id="div2" class="anchor"></div>
<div id="div3" class="anchor"></div>
<div id="div4" class="anchor"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var positions = [], //сюда сложим на загрузке страницы позиции наших "якорных" блоков, чтобы не считать их каждый раз. и сюда же положим ссылки на соответствующие a.scroll-to
    currentActive = null, //здесь будет храниться id текущего блока, чтобы не менять классы по 100 раз за одну прокрутку 
    links = $('.scroll-to'); //сохраним массив всех a.scroll-to

$(".anchor").each(function(){ //перебираем блоки, сохраняем позиции и ссылки на пункты меню
    positions.push({
        top: $(this).position().top - 100,
        a: links.filter('[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]')
    });
});

//делаем реверс массива, чтобы при скролле перебирать его с конца и выходить из цикла при нахождении
//зачем нам проверять каждый блок, если прокрутка уже ниже последнего, верно?
positions = positions.reverse(); 

$(window).on('scroll',function() {
    var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    for(var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++){
        if(positions[i].top < winTop){ //если прокрутка страницы ниже нашего блока
            if(currentActive !== i){ //и если мы еще не добавили класс текущему блоку
                currentActive = i;
                links.filter('.active').removeClass('active'); //снимаем класс .active с текущего пункта меню
                positions[i].a.addClass("active");
            }
            break; //выходим из цикла, не нужно проверять блоки, которые выше
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: просто скопировал весь код с [https://jsfiddle.net/ipshenicyn/owhLpuv9/]
в новый html и не работает все равно! Все перепроверил и ничего.

Comment: @cluster с удовольствием помогу разобраться. уточните, в каком порядке вы разместили в новом html-файле блоки js,css,html? ошибки в коноли смотрели? можете ли скинуть ссылку на этот html (на дропбоксе, к примеру) или добавить его в вопрос здесь? В данный момент я могу пообщаться с вами в чате на jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ipshenicyn/owhLpuv9/#&togetherjs=8v76HiLlen

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Hello!</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<style>
.links{
 position: fixed;
 right: 20px;
 top: 20px;
}
.scroll-to.active{color:red;}
.anchor{
 width: 20px;
 height: 400px;
}
.red{background-color: red;}
.blue{background-color: blue;}
.green{background-color: green;}
.orange{background-color: orange;}
</style>
<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: @cluster По приведенному коду не до конца ясно расположение скрипта относительно html-кода. Лучше бы ссылку на html-файл. Но, на первый взгляд, верно. А как не работает? Класс не добавляется, когда крутите? Ошибки в консоли посмотрите.

Comment: @cluster просто скопипастил код в новый html-файл. все работает: https://goo.gl/95Vkvg

Comment: Работает, спасибо.
Просто нужно было скрипт прописать в конце страницы и все заработало.